# Or operator in wordpress to match page id

Tags: php, wordpress, operators

I want to not display some code in two pages in my wordpress.

When i write this code -

```
$pageid = get_the_ID();
if($pageid != 24) { do something.... }
```

It works. and code is hidden on page id 24.

When i write this code -

```
echo $pageid = get_the_ID();
$boo=0;
if($pageid != 22) $boo=1;
if($pageid != 24) $boo=1;
if($boo==0) { do something.... }
```

But when i do this -

```
$pageid = get_the_ID();
if(($pageid != 22) || ($pageid != 24)) { do something.... }
```

It does not work, and shows the content on both pages. what is the error in this code, can anybody figure it out..??

Comment: if($pageid != 22) $boo=1;
if($pageid != 24) $boo=1;
if($boo==0) is never executed because $boo is always one so check your condition

Comment: this is working dude. $boo is 1 only when either of two conditions are true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition do not working because at both pages page_id condition is true so code is showing

Use this

```
$pageid = get_the_ID();
if(($pageid != 22) && ($pageid != 24)) { do something.... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `&&` instead of `||`.

```
$pageid = get_the_ID();
if (($pageid != 22) && ($pageid != 24)) { do something.... }
```